# Can an attacker steal information from my HTTPS page by embedding it?

Tags: web-browser, session-management

If a login page, secured with https/tls redirects to another site (also secured with https/tls) with a onetime use token (expires in a minute and has a nonce) in the querystring, can this token be hijacked if the login page is embedded in an attacker's page?

What mechanisms, if any do browsers use to prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it doesn't matter if you are using https or http. TLS only protects your data during transmission. The browser certainly must be able to read the data even if it is in some iframe, therefore whether you are using https or not is irrelevant.

Browsers are protecting your data via Cross window communication policy about which you can read here: https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication or at wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

In sort, you can't access the iframe data from the parent, unless it is from the same "origin" (**exact** same domain).

In fact, this protection may cause some problems for which the CORS mechanism was invented: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing